# Error in Eclipse: red crosses in subfolders of bin folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bin

Does anybody know what this "red x" means?

[image]

I tried to delete the `bin` folder but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

`dexedLibs` is a folder that seems to index and store recently used `.jars` in your project. Expand `dexedLibs` and check for multiple jars of the same name, which is the problem I've usually had in the past.

The error on `res` probably means you have an xml file with an error in it.